# Change mouse cursor on hovers over a VideoPlayer object in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-video-player

In order to change the cursor on hovering over certain widgets, I've been using [MouseRegion](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html) which works perfectly in combination with different child widgets. However, it doesn't work when it comes to [VideoPlayer](https://pub.dev/documentation/video_player/latest/video_player/VideoPlayer-class.html) as its child.

What I want, is to hide the mouse cursor when it hovers over a video which I'm handling with flutter's [video_player](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/main/packages/video_player/video_player) plugin and here's my simplified code:

```dart
MouseRegion(
  cursor: SystemMouseCursors.none,
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        VideoPlayer(_controller),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            _controller.value.isPlaying
                ? _controller.pause()
                : _controller.play();
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

When the video box first appears on top of the mouse cursor (on creation of the widget), the cursor disappears as intended; however, by moving it outside and reentering to the video box, it remains visible. I searched a lot to figure out the problem and I found [this open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62306) much related to what I am experiencing. However, I still believe that hiding the cursor on top of a playing video should be simple because that's simply what happens on say YouTube, a few seconds after a video is playing. Any solution will be appreciated.

I've run my code in Chrome browser and here's my flutter doctor -v:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.493], locale en-BE)
    • Flutter version 2.10.3 at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (8 days ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
    • Engine revision bd539267b4
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stacking a zero-opacity container over the video, seems to be a workaround:

```dart
Container(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0))
```

This container is invisible and expands itself to the boundaries of the video. The specified cursor (`none` in this case), will then always show when the mouse hovers or stops over the video box. The code will then look like this:

```dart
MouseRegion(
  cursor: SystemMouseCursors.none,
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        VideoPlayer(_controller),
        Container(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0)),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            _controller.value.isPlaying
                ? _controller.pause()
                : _controller.play();
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```